# Get static value from another class

Tags: c#, .net, t4

I have a static string in some class:

```
public static class SomeClass
{
    public static string MyString = "Hello World";
}
```

In T4 template file I want to invoke that static variable for conditional purposes
in order to generate SomeClass2. I thought it would be something like this:

```
<# SomeClass.MyString #>
```

I tried multiple approaches, but nothing seemed to work. I am getting error SomeClass.MyString does not exists. How can that be achieved?

Comment: is `SomeClass` in the project you want to generate a file for?

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel spotted, you are probably trying to self reference from the T4 template the same project you never built, so SomeClass doesn't exist in the (non existent?) assembly (if you reference it)

You could comment out you T4 code Then build the project , then you can reference it

Or alternatively put your "Helpers" in a different project/assembly that you can reference from from the T4-Project using 'T4 Assembly Directive'

Or Put your helpers inside the T4 Template

```
public static class FooOrBar
{
public static string What { get { return  " <#= MyHelpers.GetString(true) #> "; } }
}
<#+
public static class MyHelpers {
    public static string GetString(bool what)
    {
        return what ? "foo" : "bar";
    }
}
#>
```